# How do I change the background of a STATIC win32 control?

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

If the parent form of a (text) static control has a pattern on its background, then the area around the static control is an ugly blotch of solid color. How can I paint the background of the static control with the same pattern that its parent window uses?

I've tried this,

```
SetClassLong(retval , GCL_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG)stripes);
```

where retval was an HWND, pointing to the static control I just created,
and stripes is an HBRUSH created from a bitmap. I tried with this, too:

```
SetClassLongPtr(retval , GCLP_HBRBACKGROUND, (LONG)stripes);
```

Neither of them worked. Does anyone know how to change the background of a static control in C?

### Update

I handled the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message, which worked to an extent--it filled up the empty space in all the labels with the pattern I wanted. But the color right behind the text was just white... How can I make the pattern fill up that space as well?

Nevermind, got it.
`SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the background color for a static control by handling the [WM_CTLCOLOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432504(VS.85).aspx) message.

From the documentation

> If an application processes this message, it returns a handle to a
>   brush. The system uses the brush to
>   paint the background of the control.

The message also passes a pointer to the display context that you can use.

Comment: You mean WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC.  WM_CTLCOLOR is used in 16-bit applications (perhaps it still works for 32-bit apps ... i don't know.)

Comment: I use it in newer Win32 applications.  Compiled as both 32bit and 64bit.  Don't think what the program is compiled as makes any difference though.

Comment: @CarsonMyers but can I use `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`, I want to change background from a routine outside the CALLBACK default function, see this question for my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923691/how-can-i-set-static-controls-background-color-programmatically