# WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC is never triggered in WIN32 app

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop

I'm doing a Win32 app in C++. I have a static window and I want to change the color of the background.

I followed what is suggested here: [how can I set static controls background color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923691/how-can-i-set-static-controls-background-color-programmatically)

But in my case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC is never triggered. Do you have any idea about how what can be happening?

Here is some of my code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
                hdc = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);
                SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(2000, 50, 100));
                SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(20, 150, 100));
                if (!hBrushLabel) hBrushLabel = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(20, 150, 100));
                return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(hBrushLabel);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        hBrushLabel = NULL;
        AddBuyButtons(hWnd);
        AddText(hWnd);
        AddCartonesSlots(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (hBrushLabel) DeleteObject(hBrushLabel);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And my change function that I have checked that is called:

```
DWORD WINAPI changecolor(HWND h)
{
    if (hBrushLabel) {
        DeleteObject(hBrushLabel);
        hBrushLabel = NULL;
    }
    InvalidateRect(h, NULL, TRUE);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope you can help me!

Comment: You put the `case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` in the wrong switch statement.

Comment: OMG, I'm so stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` is its own window message, but you are processing it as though it were a menu ID for the `WM_COMMAND` message.  You need to move your `case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` handler from the inner `switch` block into the outer `switch` block:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;

    // MOVED HERE!!!
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        hdc = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);
        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(2000, 50, 100));
        SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(20, 150, 100));
        if (!hBrushLabel) hBrushLabel = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(20, 150, 100));
        return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(hBrushLabel);
        break;

    case WM_CREATE:
        hBrushLabel = NULL;
        AddBuyButtons(hWnd);
        AddText(hWnd);
        AddCartonesSlots(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (hBrushLabel) DeleteObject(hBrushLabel);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```